# JavaScript can't get the drop down selected index in a ModalPopupExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have a ModalPopupExtender with multiple drop down lists inside an UpdatePanel,i use JavaScript to open a page and pass parameters in the query string.

The drop down lists selected index is always set to 0 (the initial value when the ModalPopupExtender starts).

Any help?

JS function

```
function openInterfacePage() {
    var url = "Interface.aspx?";
    if ($('#<%= DDLPOP.ClientID %>').prop("selectedIndex") > 0) {
        url += "pop=" + $('#<%= DDLPOP.ClientID %> option:selected').val().trim();
    }
    if ($('#<%= DDLDevicePOPUP.ClientID %>').prop("selectedIndex") > 0) {
        url += "&device=" + $('#<%= DDLDevicePOPUP.ClientID %> option:selected').val().trim();
    }
    if ($('#<%= DDLDeviceInterface.ClientID %>').prop("selectedIndex") > 0) {
        url += "&interface=" + $('#<%= DDLDeviceInterface.ClientID %> option:selected').val().trim();
    }
    window.open(url, "mywindow", "toolbar=0,titlebar=0,status=0,resizable=0,menubar=0,location=1, width=920,height=500");
}
```

The prop("selectedIndex") always = 0,I think the javascript does not recognize the changes that occur after the postbacks.

Comment: Have you tried setting the onchange function to the dropdown and getting the index using javascript?

Comment: My scenario is different,there are 4 drop down lists each one is filled according to the selection of the parent list,when the user selects the last one and click a button it calls the JS function and gets the selected index of each list, so the onchange will not help in that case.

Comment: Ok, could you post the js function and explain what is not working in the function (which line of code). That would help me to figure out the issue....

Comment: I edited the main question and added the function needed

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason behind this and i am posting it in case anyone else faces the same issue.

I put my code in a user control and the javascript function was in the same user control,so there were different copies of the same function in the page (the same number of using the user control in the page).

So i removed the functions from the user control and put it in the page,so now there will be only one copy of that function. and passed the IDs of the Drop Down Lists controls as parameters to the function.